# Redirect All URL to return index.html in App Engine Java servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, restlet-2.0

The web application uses Java Restlet in the backend running on Google App Engine.

I want to return index.html for all url (/*).

Here, I don't want to use `response.redirect`, I mean, client should not aware of redirection.

I used following code in web.xml.

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.post.PostApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/v1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>StartPageServlet1</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/client/index.html</jsp-file>  
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StartPageServlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It served all /api/v1 request with Restlet. It works fine.
But /* should always return index.html. How do I do it?

Comment: Did you configure your `yaml` file?

Comment: No, i uses Java. I have web.xml file.

Comment: Did you tried modifying your `web.xml`? Could you provide its content?

Answer (score 2):

You can plug in a [filter](https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-filter) and inspect the Request URI and, based on it, decide whether or not to forward it to your home page:

`RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
rd.forward(request, response);`

Answer (score 0):

You want to serve static files only (no dynamic file, JSP file).

You may try removing all the servlets from your `web.xml` and use the `welcome-file-list` feature:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Oracle Corporation//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Have a try and let me know if this works.

Comment: i understand snippet. But i want to return index.html for all incoming requests except /js, /css, /img. I updated my questions with some more information.

Comment: No, it throws `The server has not found anything matching the request URI` error.
Error code - 404

Answer (score -1):

You can use interceptor. For each incoming request, you can set the target page as your index.html

Comment: Thanks, i did the same as you said. Like path /profile/xyz to serve index.html file. But it is requesting /profile/css/index.css and /profile/js/main.js. It throws error. It must be /css/index.css and /js/main.js. 
I think, the client is requesting based on the parent URL. how can i fix this?

Comment: I didn't get what yo u said. Are index.css and main.js files referenced from your index.html? You said you want to redirect all requests to index page. Have you succeeded in making it?

Comment: The index.html has line `<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">` 
The index.html file received correctly in the client side(I saw it Google Developer Tool -> network panel in the chrome)
The browser is trying to retrieve the css files as /profile/css/index.css which interns not exist in the server side. It must request like /css/index.css.

Comment: Your answer is confusing the OP. An "interceptor" is specific to Struts, which is a legacy request based MVC framework. But the OP is not using Struts at all.